# How can I dynamically assign newly created users to different chatter groups without hardcoding chatter group ids?

Tags: process-builder, chatter, visual-workflow

How can I dynamically assign newly created users to different chatter groups based on the market of the users using process builder without hard coding chatter group ids? As of now I have used process builder and quick action but have been hard coding the chatter group id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1st Approach:

Rather than hardcoding chatter group id you can define Custom label to store those ids and use that in process builder.

In labels are good to change Org specific ids.

> 2nd Approach:

You can also maintain Custom Metadata Type which will store mapping between user's attribute like `Market` with `Chatter Group`. It can also possible single user can be assigned to multiple chatter groups.

So, if you want to execute the logic during user creation then write after insert/update trigger on User object and execute the logic.

> 3rd Approach:

If there are existing users which you need to assign in the Chatter Group then write a batch class and execute the logic.

*You can also try out the same with flows, but apex is more optimized and easy to debug. and specially in a situation where you need to process bulk data handling*

Comment: Thanks Santanu for the solution. Will try the second approach. Appreciate the quick response and crisp solution.